# Is there a pass statement in Lua like in Python?

Tags: lua

In Python, one can use the `pass` keyword as a placeholder inside empty functions/code blocks. For example:

```py
def calc():
    pass
```

Is there an equivalent for in Lua? For example, I want to write something like:

```lua
if connect then
    pass
end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`pass` in Python does nothing. In Lua, you can just leave it empty:

```
if connect then end
```

If you want a placeholder, use an empty block

```
if connect then do end end
```

or if in Lua 5.2, use a semicolon:

```
if connect then ; end
```